passing local variable to thrd_create
Imagine this:
int foo(void* arg) {
    int v = *(int*)arg; // is arg a potential dangling pointer here?
}

thrd_t t;

int bar() {
   int my_variable = 42;
   int ret = thrd_create(&t,foo,&my_variable);
   return ret;
}

what is the order of execution here? Since foo runs on a different thread and we do not actually wait for the thread to finish/join - but thrd_create returns - is arg a potential dangling pointer?

In this case there might be a dangling pointer... It depends on if the thread run and copy the value before the bar function returns (where the life-time of my_variable ends). So what you have is a data race.
A better idea, if you want to pass only the value, is to use some explicit conversions to pass the value itself as a value:
thrd_create(..., (void *) (intptr_t) my_variable);

And
int foo(void *arg)
{
    int value = (int) (intptr_t) arg;
    // ...
}


This seems to be specific to the fact my_variable is an int/pointer compatible type. Is this common practice or is the overall situation a little strange?

@matt Usually, passing values as pointers (or the other way around) is not commonly used, no. Except when it comes to threads where it's at least not uncommon. But it only works with primitive integer types really. For anything else it's better to create a structure and use heap allocation (with malloc) to pass data.
